# How do you remove certain symbols from a string?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have some problems with regular expression. I have a dataset with money amount and in some rows there is an odd separator. And i need a regular expression to remove only the odd separator.

For example, this is a data i have:

```
user_id sum
1       10.10
2       154.24
3       19.565.02
4       2.142.00
```

And the expected result is:

```
user_id sum
1       10.10
2       154.24
3       19565.02
4       2142.00
5       1.99
```

I use python and pandas lib for data analysis.

Help please with regex. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Well, if your data is formed with 2 decimal places on the end, you can skip the regex and just use python.

For example, let's say you get all your data into a list (negate the header row) you can do the following to fix the dataset:

```
dirty = ['10.10', '154.24', '19.565.02', '2.142.00', '1.99']
# this is a list comprehension that replaces the any '.' with '' in all
# but the last three characters of your strings
clean = [item[:-3].replace('.', '') + item[-3:] for item in dirty]

>>> clean
['10.10', '154.24', '19565.02', '2142.00', '1.99']
```

Answer updated thanks to @match.

Comment: Or a slightly shorter: `[item[:-3].replace('.', '') + item[-3:] for item in dirty]` (don't know whether split/join or replace is more performant).

Comment: Hah, that's what I get for writing answers after a few beers!  Thanks.  I seem to remember split/join being better at some things, but I think that may have been a while ago.  Replace is much simpler and betterer.

Comment: @match, I timed it.  Replace is definitely better.  timeit says: 0.23 usec per loop with replace and 0.434 usec per loop with split/join so...yeah I was just being dumb.

Comment: I've lost count of the number of times I've forgotten about an obvious builtin method and gone the long way round! :-D

Answer (score 1):

slighty different way with conditional column creation using `np.where` from the `numpy` module:

```
df['sum'] = np.where(df.sum_col.str.count('\.') >= 2, df.sum_col.str.replace('.', '', 1), df.sum_col )
```

or for any amount of `.`:

```
df['sum'] = pd.to_numeric([i.replace('.','',x) for i,x in 
                           zip(df['sum'],df['sum'].str.count('\.')-1)])
```

Returns:

```
    sum_col     sum
0   10.10       10.10
1   154.24      154.24
2   19.565.02   19565.02
3   2.142.00    2142.00
```

The `sum` column is the cleaned up column

Comment: @ChickChirik you can accept ons of the answers as the correct or preferred one. This way other people with the same question can find the solution more easily.

Comment: Nice. But I'd convert it to numbers too.